Extract data of citation years in LaTeX bibliography (for histogram of cited years)
I have a fairly large bibliography for an article (using BibTeX), and I would like to make a histogram for the years that appear in the bibliography. How can I extract the data for the years from the .bbl-file?
For example, if I cite
[1] A. B. Charles, "Article title, I", (1974),
[2] A. B. Charles, "Article title, II", (1976),
[3] A. B. Charles, "Article title, III", (1976),
then I want to extract the data {1974, 1}, {1976, 2} (or some similar format, suitable for making a histogram). Alternatively, I have the .bib-file, but I am a bit hesitant of using this, since I am not 100% sure all entries therein are actually cited in my text!

Welcome to TeX.SE.

Do you have access to a utility that creates a new, smaller bib file that restricts then entries to just those cited in the paper?

@Mico Thank you. I haven't used such a utility before, but I would be happy to accept a solution that requires me to do this (it seems quite easy to do with BibTools, for example).

Indeed, BibTools will do the job in terms of creating a bib file that contains just the entries you've cited in your paper. Once you've created the new bib file, you could use a general text tool -- say, grep -- to extract all lines that contain year =, and then another tool -- say, awk -- to extract just the 4-digit years. Next, sort the numbers in ascending order. Finally, use whichever piece of software you have at hand to create a histogram. By the way, your objective, while obviously interesting, doesn't sound like it's all that much related to TeX, LaTeX, BibTeX, and friends.

@Mico Thank you! Yes, you're right-- I suppose my lack of familiarity with grep and awk makes me slow to see such solutions.

Here's an outline of a solution. It's based importantly on information received in the comments. I will assume that you have access to a computing environment -- say, Unix or one of its many descendants (which, BTW, includes MacOS) -- that gives you access to basic text tools such as awk, grep, and sed. I'm afraid I won't have much to say if you don't have access to such an environment.

I suggest you employ BibTools to create a new bib file -- say, mybib-new.bib -- from your existing bib file (say, mybib.bib). BibTools can be set to take into account information in the aux file to extract just the entries you've actually cited in your document.

Use a text tool -- say, grep -- to extract just the lines in mybib-new.bib that contain the string "year =". (Obviously, the exact search pattern has to depend on what BibTools has been set to generate.) Call the new text file, say, year-lines-only.txt.

Use another text tool -- say, awk or sed -- to extract just the four-digit year sub-strings. Send the output to another new file, say, years.txt.
If your bib file contains date fields instead of year fields, you'll have to adjust the preceding two steps suitably. E.g., make grep search for "date =" instead of for "year =", and set awk to extract just the year part of the yr-mo-dy string.

Sort the numbers in years.txt in ascending order and call the resulting file, say, years-sorted.txt.

Once you've ascertained that the basic processes are working, you may want to create a shell script to perform the preceding steps in an automated fashion, especially if you ever want to repeat this on papers you may be writing in the future.


Finally, use whatever charting software you may have at hand to create the histogram.
By the way, these tasks have very little (if anything!) to do with TeX, LaTeX, BibTeX, and friends. Nevertheless, I found your query interesting, and that's why I took the time to post an answer.

Thank you very much for taking the time. I apologize for the work you had to undertake simply due to my ignorance.
